# Regarding IP address of SUMO server

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I want to know the IP address to access SUMO ?
Due to company's firewall policy, in order to access SUMO, I need IP address information.

Thanks a lot, in advance.
BR, Jongseob Baek

Answer (score 0):

In the usual setup of sumo and veins everything is running locally on your computer. So while there are socket connections there is nothing going outside and you should just ask your administrator to allow connections to your localhost (127.0.0.1) if you really have corporate policy that forbids them.